# Shared Header Causes Multiply Defined Symbol Error

Tags: c++, header, linker

Consider the following header file example: **shared_example.h**

```
#ifndef SHARED_EX
#define SHARED_EX

const int    Shared_Int     = 1;
const char * Shared_CString = "This is a string";

#endif
```

The **shared_example.h** file is included in multiple compilation units, which leads the linker to (correctly) complain that:

`error LNK2005: "char const * const Shared_CString" (?Shared_CString@@3PBDB) already defined in First_Compilation_Unit.obj`

Removing the Shared_CString constant from this file eliminates the issue.

So, I have two questions.

First, why doesn't the Shared_Int constant trigger the same issue?

Second, what is the appropriate way to allow separate compilation units to make use of the same constant string value?

Comment: Are you sure you are coding in `c++`, or just compiling with a c/c++ compiler?

Comment: @Itsik, I'm attempting to code in C++ but it's possible that's just a pipe dream.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The first declaration is of a constant integral value. In C++, `const` has internal linkage by default.

The second declaration is of a pointer to `const char`. That declaration is not `const` itself, and has no other linkage specifiers, so it does not have internal linkage. If you changed the declaration to `const char * const` it would then become a const pointer to `const char` and have internal linkage.

Comment: Concise and clear.  Excellent.  Any advice on a good source for reading up on internal vs external linkage?

Comment: @Greg, aside from the C++ standard, IBM has some really good documentation on C++ (http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr020.htm). Of course, your compiler documentation should also have some good documentation on this and other C++ intricacies that they support.

Answer (score 4):

**shared_example.h**

```
#ifndef SHARED_EX
#define SHARED_EX

extern const int    Shared_Int;
extern const char * Shared_CString;

#endif
```

**shared_example.c**

```
const int    Shared_Int     = 1;
const char * Shared_CString = "This is a string";
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid this particular solution, due to the fact that my shared_example.h files derives from header with no associated body.  It is certainyl another way to manage it tho.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Making them static will solve the issue.
You are not seeing the Shared_Int because you are not using it in more then one of the c modules that you compile.

Edit: My bad - what I say is valid for C. Didn't saw the c++ tag. Sorry